# GUID From Reflection of Members

Tags: c#, reflection, guid

Is there a way I can get GUI of type members?
e.g: GUID of ConstructorInfo, PropertyInfo, FieldInfo, MethodInfo and EventInfo?

i can only see type.ReflectedType.GUID (e.g property.ReflectedType.GUID)
but GUID generated was the class GUID (w/c is the type)

Comment: What makes you think that these other objects *have* guids associated with them? If you look at the documentation for the GUID for types, you'll see that it can be manually set using the `GuidAttribute` class - and if you look at that type, you'll notice that it cannot be applied to type members such as properties, methods, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `Type.GUID` to get the pre-defined GUID registered by GuidAttribute attribute. But the GUID is not well documented, use with care.

```
typeof(ConstructorInfo).GUID
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.guid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bad idea if you will use that GUID as an identifier for types in your application (in Dictionaries or similar classes). Instead use the type directly.

So instead of `Dictionary<string, whatever>` use a `Dictionary<Type, whatever>`.